# How to run ":use db" command using liquibase (neo4j plugin)?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, liquibase, liquibase-cli

I am trying to create a new database in Neo4j and run some cypher queries in that newly created db.

I am able to create a new db using the Liquibase update command. But I am unsure how to write a changeset for the command ":use {dbname}".

Or is there any way where I could specify the database name in the changeset?

I am unable to find any documentation related to this use case or any liquibase command which might serve me.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Database is usually specified in the connection URL, why do you want to change it afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

A single execution targets a single database.
This is configured through the connection URL, as [documented here](https://www.neo4j.com/labs/liquibase/docs/reference-connection-uri/#detailed-configuration).

If you need to target multiple databases, you will have to run the CLI several times. If some change sets apply to only one database, Liquibase's [context and labels](https://www.liquibase.com/blog/contexts-vs-labels) can help (you can filter per DB for each CLI execution).